# QDialog with Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint incorrect after calling exec the second time

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog, maximize-window

I have a `QDialog` with a maximize button and a small test runner.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include "MyDialog.h"

    int main(int argc, char** args) {
        QApplication app(argc, args);
        auto widget=new MyDialog;
        auto btn = new QPushButton("Show");
        btn->show();
        QObject::connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]() {widget->exec(); });
        app.exec();
    }
```

**MyDialog.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <QDialog>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QFrame>

class MyDialog : public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyDialog(QWidget* parent = nullptr) : QDialog(parent) {     
        auto window = new QMainWindow;
        auto frame = new QFrame;
        frame->setLayout(new QHBoxLayout);
        frame->layout()->addWidget(new QLabel("Test"));
        window->setCentralWidget(frame);
        setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
        layout()->setMargin(0);
        layout()->addWidget(window);
        setWindowFlags(windowFlags() | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint | Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
    }
};
```

In my test runner I press **[Show]**, then I maximize my dialog. Now I close the dialog by pressing the cross. Then I press **[Show]** again. After that I got the wrong rendering of my dialog.

How can I fix this behavior. The `QLabel("Test")`should occupy the whole screen.

[image: Wrong rendering of my dialog]